# Is this usage correct: "The late Professor Emeritus Professor Johannes Kinfu dies"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw it as a headline [on the Addis Ababa University website](http://www.aau.edu.et/the-late-professor-emeritus-professor-johannes-kinfu-dies/). Does *late* in this instance mean something else?

Comment: "The late John Doe" means "John Doe, who died recently".

Comment: Depends.  Was he a coward?  The valiant taste of death but once.

Comment: Someone missed the whole purpose in writing headlines when they wrote that one.

Comment: Only live people die, then they become _late_ in that sense. Late ones do not die. Do you realize the word Professor also shows up twice in the headline?

Comment: @YosefBaskin To be fair, He was the Redundancy Professor of Redundancy.

Comment: It should read "Professor Emeritus Johannes Kinfu Dies".  Good catch!  The website is not alone in needing better proofreading;  The Washington Post needs better proofreading too.

Comment: Not only do late people not die, you also stop being (professor) emeritus when you become late, and you can't be a professor emeritus professor. I think they may have hired one of those monkeys that are busy typing out the collected works of Shakespeare to write this headline.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - One would almost suspect that the redundancy is intentional.  Perhaps this is a pre-release of the April 1st of April edition.

Comment: @jimm101 I believe that professorship was endowed by the family of the late Chauncey Redundancy, so the title is OK. But was he retired at the time he died?

Comment: It's not the professor's fault that the writer flubbed up the title.

Comment: What do you mean by "something else"? What do you currently think it means?

Comment: "Does late in this instance mean something else?": Maybe they expected him to die sooner.

Comment: Something else could mean that the prof was due to lecture at 10 a.m.. Arriving at 10.15 the late professor rushed across the road without looking  and was killed. The late professor dies. I'm sure it doesn't mean that though.

Comment: Emiritus Professors are common place. If he'd been the late Regius Professor then that would have merited a mention dead or alive.

Answer (score 0):

Although not commonly used in this way today, *late* can mean "former" [OxfordDictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/late).
However, from what I can gather from [AAU](http://www.aau.edu.et/), Johannes Kinfu was a *living* Professor Emeritus when he passed away.
Current usage would make using *late* to mean "former" tricky, and not worth trying.

Comment: But the "Emeritus" would imply he is a former professor....can you stop bring an "emeritus"? Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [tautology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology) to me. IMHO, the headline should be:

'**Professor XYZ dies**'

Then, when talking about him: 'The late Professor XYZ ...'